# 2 ways of running python program

Tags: python, syntax

I am learning Python now. There are 2 ways of running python in the terminal.

one is 
`python xx.py` 
 
another `./xx.py`

The first way works for me, but when I am trying to run using the second option, I get

```
-bash: ./hello.py: Permission denied
```

I can run the python program one way or another, but I would really like to know why, and what command should use to grant permission to run this using `./`

Thanks!

Comment: If your script name is `__main__.py` you can also invoke the script using `python ./`

Comment: While a bit esoteric, this is useful trivia. I once used a similar method to 'break' into an embedded Python interpreter.. When python does it's 'import', it'll check every path in PYTHONPATH and sys.paths to load a program..) So if you have an embedded Python instance, you can drop something like `__main__.py` into your CWD, or site.py and it'll override whatever the embedded instance is looking for..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order to be executable, the script must be granted execute permissions via chmod: `chmod +x filename.py` or the like.

Answer (score 2):

This should probably be migrated to unix.stackexchange.com

You need to make sure it has permissions set correctly,chmod 755 hello.py

For interpreted scripts, you need not only to be executable, but readable so that the script interpreter can read the program.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to [change permissions](http://gd.tuwien.ac.at/linuxcommand.org/lts0070.html) on the file, to allow it to be executable. In bash:

```
chmod +755 ./xx.py
```

Then `./xx.py` will work. If it doesn't, you'll need to make sure that you're using a [shebang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29) correctly.

Answer (score 1):

First grant 'execute' permission to the file

```
$ chmod +x filename.py
```

Then you will be able to run the script:

```
$ ./filename.py
```